# ElasticSearch combined OR and AND clauses in filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ElasticSearch 7.7 query with several filters (criteria that I don't want to be counted for the score), that look like that:

```json
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "gender": "female"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to add a OR clause to two gender filters, in order to filter for all documents with a `type=4` AND (`gender=female` OR `gender=unisex`). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "gender": "female"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "gender": "unisex"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I wasn't sure if I was supposed to use a `bool` to combine the two AND.